# Inheritance from template class or multiple constructors?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, boost

Considering the following **template** class to work with different **boost::asio** sockets (i.e., TCP/UDP/Serial):

```
template<class T>
class Connection:: private boost::noncopyable, public  std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection<T>> {

            Connection(const std::shared_ptr<IoServiceWrapper> &ioService, 
                       const std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context::strand> &ioStrand);

  ..
}
```

where each **boost** socket object requires specific parameters while opening the connection, e.g., **dstAddr** and **dstPort** to create the endpoint for TCP/UDP sockets, and **portName**, **baudRate**, **serial_port_base** parameters (e.g., character size, stop bits etc.) for the serial port.

What is the best approach to provide these parameters which are related to the specific type **T** of the boost socket?

I was thinking to two possible solutions:

1) Inheritance from the template class, such as:

```
class TcpPortConnection : public Connection<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> {

public:

TcpPortConnection(
    const std::shared_ptr<IoServiceWrapper> &ioService,
    const std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context::strand> &ioStrand,
    const std::string &dstAddress, uint16_t dstPort)
    : Connection(ioService, ioStrand), _dstAddress(dstAddress), _dstPort(dstPort) {}

...

}
```

2) Multiple constructors for the template class, such as:

```
template<class T>
class Connection:: private boost::noncopyable, public  std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection<T>> {

            Connection(const std::shared_ptr<IoServiceWrapper> &ioService, 
                       const std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context::strand> &ioStrand,
                       const std::string &dstAddress, 
                       uint16_t dstPort);


            Connection(const std::shared_ptr<IoServiceWrapper> &ioService, 
                       const std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context::strand> &ioStrand,
                       const std::string &portName, 
                       uint32_t baudRate,
                       boost::tuples::tuple<boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size,
                                            boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity,
                                            boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits> SerialParams);

  ..
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution to the previous approaches?